# How to get a dictionary from a ZoneAwarePromise

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I am currently working on my graduation project for my apprenticeship and I would like to ask a question about it.

I am developing an Ionic App which basically calculates leasing instalements for customers.
The app gets information from another project via HTTP Request (the return is a dictionary) and it automatically saves it as a ZoneAwarePromise.
My goal is to get the information and show it in a list on the mainpage. How can I achieve this?
Thank you for your help.
This is the code sample I use for the http request:

```
    const transport = new HTTPTransport("url");
const client = new Client(new RequestManager([transport]));
const result = client.request({method: "getRaten", params: { logname: logname, pwd: pwd, werte}});
```

Comment: Hello, could you please edit your post to add the most relevant parts of the code? Thanks :)

Comment: I added the most important function. The return is a dictionary from my python backend.